# How to make my Python Machine Learning model keep learning as I feed it more data each day?

Tags: python, service, scikit-learn

I have a python Machine Learning script which learns from Firewall log data. I am using Random Forest Classifier in it. If I run it as a service is it possible to train the model, again and again, each day whenever last day's Firewall logs are received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[These](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) are the estimators in sklearn that support what you want to do and unfortunately for you Random Forest isn't one of them, so you will have to refit every time you add data.

If you insist on sticking with Random Forest, one option would be to reduce the number of features (based on the classifier you currently have) to increase the speed of refitting your classifier.